# How can I test a multiline output in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, stdout, ex-unit

How can I test the following code?

```
["one", "two", "three"]) |> Enum.each(&IO.puts(&1))
one
two
three
:ok
```

My test currently looks like this, but is failing because `IO.puts` returns `:ok` rather that the strings, and probably does not include newline characters in a complete string.

```
assert ["one", "two", "three"]) |> Enum.each(&IO.puts(&1)) == """
one
two
three
"""
```

Perhaps `IO.puts` is the wrong function for this use case. If so, what alternative might I use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`capture_io`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.CaptureIO.html).

```
fun = fn -> ["one", "two", "three"] |> Enum.each(&IO.puts/1) end
assert capture_io(fun) == "one\ntwo\nthree\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Is there a way that doctest can handle leading whitespace?

"  my_string  "

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I looked it up and doctest does not (any longer?) support capturing io. I edited my answer, as the part about doctest was wrong.